# Bibtex change string names

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I would like to insert an entry in my bibliography in Lyx and I am using JabRef to do so.

For instance, I have:

```
@InCollection{Hawthorne2005-HAWTCF-2,
  author    = {John Hawthorne},
  title     = {The Case for Closure},
  booktitle = {Contemporary Debates in Epistemology},
  publisher = {Blackwell},
  year      = {2005},
  editor    = {Matthias Steup and Ernest Sosa},
  pages     = {26-43},
}
```

And in my bibliography I get: John Hawthorne. The case for closure. In Matthias Steup and Ernest Sosa, editors,
Contemporary Debates in Epistemology. Blackwell, 2005.

I would like to change part of the texts.
For instance, instead of getting "pages" I would like to prin "pp.", and I would like to change also the string "editors" with another string.

How can I do this in Lyx?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's easier to customise (via latex code) if you use  `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use it in the lyx preamble but i don't know which command to write in

Comment: Could you post  a minimal, yet complete code illustrating your problem?